# Highcharter and Flexdashboard inconsistency in R

Tags: r, flexdashboard, r-highcharter

I am trying to create dashboard using `flexdashboard` and `highcharter` in R and I noticed strange behavior of `highcharter`. Below is my code snippet, there supposed to be two sub-menu tabs "Baltic countries" and "Rest of the Europe", but chart do not pop-out in tab "Rest of the Europe". The problem seems to be in `highcharter` package, because eveyrthing is ok then I use package downloaded from CRAN, and the problem appears when I use `devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")` version. Any ideas how to fix it using latter version of `highcharter`?

````
Tests
=======================================================================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade data-width=700 .colored }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Baltic countries {.no-padding}
```{r fig.height=7}
highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime",dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b')) %>%
  hc_add_series(baltic_data, type="spline",hcaes(x=date,y=round(total_tests_imp), group = location), showInLegend = F, marker = list(enabled = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, borderWidth = 1.5, headerFormat = "", pointFormat = paste("Date: {point.x:%Y-%m-%d} <br>", "Total tests: <b>{point.y}<br>", "Country: <b>{series.name}</b>")) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Number of tests in Baltic countries") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Active testing started in the second part of March")
````

````
 ### Rest of the Europe {.no-padding}
```{r fig.height=7}
highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime",dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b')) %>%
  hc_add_series(rest_europe, type="spline",hcaes(x=date,y=round(total_tests_imp), group = location), showInLegend = F, marker = list(enabled = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, borderWidth = 1.5, headerFormat = "", pointFormat = paste("Date: {point.x:%Y-%m-%d} <br>", "Total tests: <b>{point.y}<br>", "Country: <b>{series.name}</b>")) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Number of tests in rest of the Europe") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Active testing started in the second part of March")
````

**Dashboard Menu:**

[image]